# How to keep annotations on the same line when formatting PHP code

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I have some custom annotations which should go exactly before a variable value

```
$var = /* @text */'Some translatable text';
```

After formatting it becomes

```
$var = /* @text */
'Some translatable text';
```

How to disable inserting new lines after the annotations?

Comment: edit php codestyle settings/scheme in preferences

Comment: Which option? There are a lot, and I tried almost all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this at the moment.
Feel free to submit a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes.